# Print the number of distict words for each letter in a file

Tags: linux

I need to take a file and print the number of distict words that start in each letter of the english alphabet, in a descending order of word count. For example if the file is "my nice name is Mike Meller" then the output should be:

3 M
2 N
1 I

I need to do this in a piped sequence of commands... I know commands like `wc -m` and `wc -w` but I have no idea how to iterate over each character and print it in the same way and then sort it like they want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep -o '[a-zA-Z]+' file.txt | tr a-z A-Z | cut -c1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: this gives me a list of all words ... i need a list of characters and next to each character the number of all words that started with the character

Comment: I have fixed this.

Comment: amazing! but, it also gives me numbers and special characters, and it does not differentiate between lowercase and uppercase... maybe adding `tr a-z A-Z` after `file.txt |` will help with this?

Comment: Yes, this should work. The new pattern should only match letters. If you need letters with accents (e.g. umlauts) you should add them to the pattern and the `tr` replacement.

Comment: this is good but for some reason it also shows me special letters... any way to not include them?

Comment: Can you give me an example for such letters? The egrep pattern `[a-zA-Z]+` shouldn't match them.

Comment: it shows me `©` and `§` and `×` and couple of white chars

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I include these characters into my test file, they aren't printed.

Comment: how can i also paste only the distict words? for example if "hello" appeared 3 times in the text, it will count it only once